# proving that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<-3$ which are the negative roots of $f(x)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, roots

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Given
> \begin{align*}
> f(x) &= x^4 + (-m - 2n + 6)x^3 + (mn - 5m - 8n + 10)x^2\\
> &\quad + (3mn - 7m - 8n)x + mn-m-n-7,
> \end{align*}
> if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are two negative roots of $f(x)=0$, show that $\alpha_1+\alpha_2< -3$ for $m,n\ge 4$.

I took some values of $m,n$ and found the following:

$m=n=4$, $\alpha_1=-2.476, \alpha_2=-0.621$;

$m=5,n=4$, $\alpha_1=-2.49, \alpha_2=-0.59$

I tried some other values of $m,n$,
In all the above cases, I am getting $\alpha_1+\alpha_2<-3$.

But I am not able to prove it. Can someone please help me out?

**NOTE**:

I found the following. I obtained $-1<\alpha_1<-k$ and $-3<\alpha_2<-3+k$
where $k$ is some function of $m$ and $n$.

I took $m=4,n=5$ and I got $\alpha_1=-2.492<-3+0.55, \alpha_2=-0.592<-0.55$.
I took some other values of $m,n$ and obtained similar stuff.
So I think my guess is correct.

**Is there any way to find $k$ such that $k$ is a function of $m,n$?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119700/discussion-on-question-by-math-freak-proving-that-alpha-1-alpha-2-3-which-a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
f(-3) &= mn + 2m + 5n + 2 > 0, \\
f(-3/2) &= \frac{-20mn + 26m - 4n + 5}{16} < 0,\\
f(0) &= mn - m - n - 7 > 0, \\
f(m) &= -m^3 n+m^3-5 m^2 n+3 m^2-7 m n-m-n-7 < 0, \\
f(2m + 2n) &= 8 m^4+28 m^3 n+32 m^2 n^2+12 m n^3+28 m^3+78 m^2 n+66 m n^2\\
&\quad +16 n^3+26 m^2+51 m n+24 n^2-m-n-7\\
& > 0.
\end{align}
(Note: Simply letting $m = 4 + s, n = 4 + t$ for $s, t \ge 0$, all the inequalities are obvious.)

Thus, $f(x) = 0$ has four real roots $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ located in the following intervals respectively
$$x_1 \in (-3, -3/2), \quad x_2 \in (-3/2, 0), \quad x_3 \in (0, m), \quad x_4 \in (m, 2m+2n).$$

We need to prove that $x_1 + x_2 < -3$ or $x_2 < -3 - x_1$.

Since $-3 - x_1 \in (-3/2, 0)$, it suffices to prove that $f(-3-x_1) > 0$.

Since $f(x_1) = 0$, it suffices to prove that $f(-3-x_1) - f(x_1) > 0$ that is
$$(2x_1 + 3)\Big((m+2n)x_1^2 + 3(m+2n)x_1 + m+2n + 3\Big) > 0.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$x_1 > - \frac{3}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{5m + 10n - 12}{4m + 8n}}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$f\left(- \frac{3}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{5m + 10n - 12}{4m + 8n}}\right) > 0$$
that is
$$\frac{m^3+2 m^2 n+2 m n^2+4 n^3-m^2-10 m n-16 n^2+3 m+6 n+9}{(m+2 n)^2} > 0$$
which is true. (Note: Simply letting $m = 4 + s, n = 4 + t$ for $s, t\ge 0$, this inequality is obvious.)

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

For @Math_Freak: The Maple code for the last two equations is given by

```
f := x^4+(-m-2*n+6)*x^3+(m*n-5*m-8*n+10)*x^2+(3*m*n-7*m-8*n)*x+m*n-m-n-7
x := -3/2+Q
f1 := collect(expand(f), Q)
f2 := subs({Q^2 = (5*m+10*n-12)/(4*m+8*n), Q^3 = (5*m+10*n-12)*Q/(4*m+8*n), Q^4 = ((5*m+10*n-12)/(4*m+8*n))^2}, f1)
factor(f2)
```

Comment: Nice ,but how did you even think of checking the sign of $g(y)$ for the ertain values ,is it jsut random guessing or motivated by computer ,and also why did you think of subbing $x=-3/2+\sqrt{5}/2y$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore  Actually, if $f(a) f(b) < 0$, then there is at least one real root on $(a, b)$. We need to prove that $x_1 + x_2 < -3$ that is $(x_1 + 3/2) + (x_2 + 3/2) < 0$. Let $x_1 + 3/2 = y_1, x_2 + 3/2 = y_2$. We need to prove that $y_1 + y_2 < 0$.

Comment: LOL that was not my question  I know that, I am asking How you thought of g(2m+2n+3/2)  and checking  its sign

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore I edited the answer since the substitution is not necessary.
For your question, we may use bisection to find the points.
For example, first, $f(0) > 0$; second, since $f(\infty) = \infty$, we may find
a large $c$ such that $f(c) > 0$, e.g., $c = 10m + 10n$. Then we check the middle point
of $0$ and $10m + 10n$, i.e., $c_1 = 5m + 5n$, if $f(c_1) < 0$, OK, otherwise,
check the middle point of $0$ and $c_1$ and so on. Finally, we find $c_0 = \frac{5}{8}(m+n)$ such that $f(c_0) < 0$. Thus, $x_3 \in (0, \frac{5}{8}(m+n))$ and $x_4 \in (\frac{5}{8}(m+n), 10m + 10n)$.

Comment: Am I missing something ? The answer says: $-3<x_1<-1.5, -1.5<x_2<0$, But wont it imply $x_1+x_2<-1.5$? How do we get $x_1+x_2<-3$ from here?

Comment: @Math_Freak Because $x_1 + x_2 < -3$ implies $x_1 + x_2 < -1.5$. I don't prove $x_1 + x_2 < -3$ from $-3 < x_1 < -1.5$ and $-1.5 < x_2 < 0$  which is just some estimate of the location of $x_1, x_2$. I start the proof from the next paragraph that is "we need to prove that $x_1 + x_2 < -3$ ..."

Comment: Its good,however some of those calculations (especially the last one ) can be extremely strenous by hand ,but if  no better solution comes in I guess this will get the bounty

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes, the last one is quite complicated.

Comment: @RiverLi; how did you do the last 2-3  calculations? was it by hand?

Comment: @Math_Freak I use Maple. I think it takes 20-30 minutes by hand for the whole calculations.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask how to do the calculations in Maple?

Comment: @Math_Freak We need manipulations of polynomials, such as expand, solve, collect, factor, simplify, subs, etc. For example, to avoid radicals, we may let $x = -\frac{3}{2} + Q$ where $Q = \sqrt{\frac{5m + 10n - 12}{4m + 8n}}$, then insert $x = -\frac{3}{2} + Q$ to $f(x)$ and simplify it by using $Q^2 = \frac{5m + 10n - 12}{4m + 8n}$.

Comment: @RiverLi; i did all the calculations except the last one by hand , i cant verify that, can you please help how to do it in Maple

Comment: @Math_Freak You mean $f\left(- \frac{3}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{5m + 10n - 12}{4m + 8n}}\right) > 0$?

Comment: @RiverLi; yes absolutely, i am stuck there, how do i calculate 4th power?

Comment: @Math_Freak I put the Maple code at the end of this answer.

Comment: @RiverLi; thanks a lot, is Maple chargeable? do you know of any free software which can do these calculations?

Comment: @Math_Freak Free Computer Algebra Systems (CAS), You may try Maxima or Sagemath? See https://maxima.sourceforge.io/compalg.html

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1 < x_2 < 0$ be two negative solutions and I will obtain a bound:
$$x_2 <-\dfrac{3}{10}(5+\sqrt{10})\approx-2.4487.$$

First, rewrite the polynomial as:
\begin{align}
f(x,m,n) = (x^2+3x+1)mn  
\\-(x^3+5x^2+7x+1)m  
\\-(2x^3+8x^2+8x+1)n 
\\+(x^4+6x^3+10x^2-7) 
\end{align}
As my previous update and @RiverLi's comment said, we can obtain the simple bound:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1 < x_1 < x_2 < \lambda_2 < 0,
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_{1,2} = \dfrac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ are the roots of the equation $x^2+3x+1 = 0,$ by simply considering $f(\lambda_i,m,n).$ But this is not strong enough because we want an upper bound on $x_1.$ Therefore, for a small $\varepsilon > 0$ to be chosen later, consider the equation:
$$x^2+3x+1 = -\varepsilon\,\,(1)$$
and call its roots $x_{1,2}^{\varepsilon} = \dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{5-4\varepsilon}}{2},\,x_1^{\varepsilon}<x_2^{\varepsilon} .$ The nice thing about this is that if $x < 0$ is root of $(1),$ then we have a nice form for:
\begin{align}
f(x,m,n) = -\varepsilon mn
\\+(x\varepsilon+2\varepsilon +1)m
\\+(2x\varepsilon+2\varepsilon+1)n
\\+(\varepsilon^2+\varepsilon-7-3x)
\end{align}
which we will call $(2).$
We want to choose $\varepsilon$ so that $f(x_1^{\varepsilon})$ is negative, which will give $x_1 < x_1^{\varepsilon}.$

One can immediately see that:
$$2x_1^{\varepsilon}\varepsilon+2\varepsilon+1 = 1-\varepsilon -\varepsilon\sqrt{5-4\varepsilon}<0\iff 0.344446\approx\varepsilon_0 < \varepsilon < 1.25$$
where $\varepsilon_0$ is the unique positive solution of $1-\varepsilon -\varepsilon\sqrt{5-4\varepsilon}=0.$ Choosing this $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_0$ will give a slightly better bound, but when I was doing it by hand I found $0.35$ works, which gives the quadratic equation:
$$20x^2+60x+27 = 0\implies x_1^{\varepsilon} = -\dfrac{3}{10}(5+\sqrt{10})\approx-2.4487.$$

For this chosen value, the only thing left to show is that $f(x_1^\varepsilon) < 0.$ We automatically know that the coefficient of $n$ is negative by our choice and the free coefficient is trivially negative as well. For the remaining part:
$$-\varepsilon mn+(x\varepsilon+2\varepsilon +1)m \leq m\left(1+x\varepsilon-2\varepsilon\right)=m\cdot\dfrac{2-7\varepsilon - \varepsilon\sqrt{5-4\varepsilon}}{2}<0,$$
which can be verified by hand for $\varepsilon = 0.35.$

To conclude, we then have:
$$x_2+x_1 < -\dfrac{3}{10}(5+\sqrt{10}) +\dfrac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx -2.83.$$
But all of this was done to obtain an explicit upper bound on $x_1$, which we previously do not have. So now by considering $x^2+3x+1 = \varepsilon$ for small, suitable $\varepsilon >0,$ I hope to better the not-so-tight upper bound $x_2:$
$$x_2<\lambda_2 = \dfrac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx -0.381,$$
next time I got some time on my hand.

Comment: Let $x_1 < x_2 < 0$ be the two negative real roots. We have $f(-3)>0, f(-1) < 0, f(0) > 0$ and $f(\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}) > 0$, $f(\frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}) > 0$. Thus $\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2} < x_1$ and $x_2 < \frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: @RiverLi, yea that's exactly what I did in the edit. The difference is we don't have to explicitly plug in $\dfrac{-3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ to see their signs. I am thinking that by considering the roots of $x^2+3x+1 = \pm\varepsilon$, we can probably get the reverse bound on $x_1.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha_{i,m,n}$ be the $i^\text{th}$ root of $f(x;m,n)$ in ascending order. It is shown that for $m>4,n>4$

$$
\begin{align}
&\alpha_{1,\infty,\infty}<\alpha_{1,m,n}<\alpha_{1,4,4}\\
&\alpha_{2,4,4}<\alpha_{2,m,n}<\alpha_{2,\infty,\infty}
\end{align}
$$

Numerically,

$$
\begin{align}
&-2.618\ldots<\alpha_{1,m,n}<-2.476\ldots\\
&-0.621\ldots<\alpha_{2,m,n}<-0.3819\ldots
\end{align}
$$
leading to the bound
$$
\alpha_{1,m,n}+\alpha_{2,m,n}<-2.858\ldots
$$

The proof is via observing the change of sign of $f$ at the boundaries of the intervals $(\alpha_{1,\infty,\infty}~,\alpha_{1,4,4})$ and $(\alpha_{2,4,4}~,\alpha_{2,\infty,\infty})$, as tabulated below:

| $x$ | $sgn(f(x,m,n))$ |
| --- | --- |
| $\alpha_{1,\infty,\infty}$ | $+1$ |
| $\alpha_{1,4,4}$ | $-1$ |
| $\alpha_{2,4,4}$ | $-1$ |
| $\alpha_{2,\infty,\infty}$ | $+1$ |

---

The infinity roots are $(-3\pm\sqrt{5})/2$.